# mysql. slipt date and time and set min as checkin and maximum as checkout

Tags: mysql

i hv an table in MySQL in which my users attendance store,  i want to split it and min time as checkin and max time as checkout (eg, id,date,checkin,checkout)

my table is as ...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share proper table structure and some sample data to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `DATE()`, `TIME()` and `GROUP BY` functions

Lets create a sample db

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `check_in` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `user_id`, `check_in`) VALUES
(1, 3, '2021-07-04 10:18:19'),
(2, 3, '2021-07-04 11:18:19'),
(3, 3, '2021-07-04 13:18:19'),
(4, 3, '2021-07-05 08:18:19'),
(5, 3, '2021-07-05 20:18:19');
```

And Query is...

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    DATE(`check_in`) as date,
    TIME(MIN(`check_in`)) AS CheckIn,
    TIME(MAX(`check_in`)) AS Checkout
FROM
    `my_table`
GROUP BY
    user_id,  DATE(`check_in`)
```

And the result will be

| user_id | date | CheckIn | Checkout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-07-04 | 10:18:19 | 13:18:19 |
| 3 | 2021-07-05 | 08:18:19 | 20:18:19 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07db2f23144ad24eb00b430ddd64fb61)*